# 'NSString' is not a subtype of 'UILAbel' in Swift View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsstring

I'm currently reading the book, Beginning iPhone Development with Swift and having some trouble in the third chapter's exercise. It basically has you created two buttons (both linked to the same action) and a label that has its text change depending on which button you press. I've followed the example code exactly but still get the error `NSString' is not a subtype of 'UILAbel` over my last line within the function. All three UI elements are linked as they should but don't know what its not working.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!

  @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let title = sender.titleForState(.Normal)!
    let plainText = "\(title) button pressed"
    statusLabel = plainText
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you cannot assign an `NSString` to a `UILabel`.

```
statusLabel = plainText // invalid
```

What you can do:

```
statusLabel.text = plainText
```